# MultiIndexing based on row values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Trying to create a simple program that finds negative values in a pandas dataframe and combines them with their matching row. Basically I have data that looks like this:

```
LastName DrugName RxNumber Amount ClientTotalCost
ADAMS     Drug     100001    30          10.69
ADAMS     Drug     100001    -25         -8.95
...
```

The idea is that I need to match up fills and refunds, then combine them into a single row. So, in the example above we'd have one row that looks like this:

```
LastName DrugName RxNumber Amount ClientTotalCost
ADAMS      Drug    100001    5         1.74
```

Also, if a refund doesn't match  to a fill row, I'm supposed to just delete it, which I've been accomplishing with .drop()

I'm imagining I can build a multiindex for this somehow, where each row that's a negative is marked as a refund and each fill row is marked as a fill. Then I just have some kind of for loop that goes through the list and attempts to match a certain number of times based on name/number of refunds.

Here's what I was trying:

```
pbm_negative_index = raw_pbm_data.loc['LastName','DrugName','RXNumber','ClientTotalCost']
    names = pbm_negative_index = raw_pbm_data.loc[: , 'LastName']
    unique_names = unique(pbm_negative_index)
    for n in unique_names:
        edf["Refund"] = edf["ClientTotalCost"].shift(1, fill_value=edf["ClientTotalCost"].head(1)) < 0
```

This obviously doesn't work and I'd like to use the indexing tools in Pandas to achieve a similar result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your specification reduces to two simple steps:

- aggregate +ve & -ve matching rows
- drop remaining -ve rows after aggregation

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""LastName DrugName RxNumber Amount ClientTotalCost
ADAMS     Drug     100001    30          10.69
ADAMS     Drug     100001    -25         -8.95
ADAMS2   Drug. 100001 -5   -1.95
"""), sep="\s+")

# aggregate
dfa = df.groupby(["LastName","DrugName","RxNumber"],as_index=False).agg({"Amount":"sum","ClientTotalCost":"sum"})
# drop remaining -ve amounts
dfa = dfa.drop(dfa.loc[dfa.Amount.lt(0)].index)
```

|  | LastName | DrugName | RxNumber | Amount | ClientTotalCost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | ADAMS | Drug | 100001 | 5 | 1.74 |